# manipulate css border with javascript to custom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wondering if there is a way to manipulate CSS `border:` edges to custom edge / border type with JavaScript or jQuery?

For example making a slightly; jagged, zigzag, or tear looking border edge for specified border without `background: url('imageofedge.png');`?

Curious if something like this is possible in effort to load less images across, for speed and performance.

*Note: //* I'm aware of CSS border property and know what capabilities are there, wondering if there is an ability to manipulate for custom option using jQuery / JS.

Comment: Have you looked how can you style borders with CSS(3)? Examples in W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp

Comment: Yes. Seeking to know if can ultimately do more, and custom option, using script -- without loading the custom option as a background image.

Comment: JavaScript directly is not used to style elements, it's either CSS or HTML. You can use JavaScript to help to achieve different kind of stylings. Example, if you do `$("#element").css("border-radius", "25px");` it is JavaScript, but it uses CSS(3) to style it. Did this make any sense?

Comment: Some people have been using the canvas for more advanced styling options. See: http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/108/CanvasInput-HTML5-Canvas-Text-Input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is **NO** option with **CSS** so why use jquery? (yet)

Just do something like this:

```
border-image: url(imageofedge.png);
```

You can read more in [DevDocs](http://devdocs.io/css/border-image)

Comment: I guess this is the best answer I'll get :(